# What is a faster alternative to using document.getElementById('element-id').innerHTML?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm making a simple step-by-step wizard for my website which asked viewers questions about their custom order. I've been using JavaScript to replace the content of each "page" with the document.getElementById('element-id').innerHTML command; however, it seems really slow and awkward to add entire divs as a string. For example, some of the code looks something like this:

```
function loadNextStep() {

   document.getElementById('content').innerHTML = 'This is some content.<br>It seems like I need to write everything in one line to make the command work properly.<br><input type="date" id="date-picker" value=""></input>'
}
```

I'd love to be able to write some multi-line html code, and say "replace everything with this new html."

Is there a faster way of doing the same thing?

Thank you again!

Comment: getElementById is the faster then other. How many times did you call loadNextStep function ?

Comment: `content.innerHTML` is a shorthand

Comment: Also why don't you simply use multiple HTML files, with links to jump from one to the next? page1.html, page2.html etc.

Comment: about speed test you can check [getElementById vs querySelector vs getElementsByClassName vs getElementsByName](https://measurethat.net/Benchmarks/Show/1144/1/getelementbyid-vs-queryselector-vs-getelementsbyclassna#latest_results_block)

Comment: Also you can use backticks `\`` instead of single `'` or double `"` quotes. Backticks allow multi-line strings.

Comment: Thank you so much! I think the backticks are exactly what I needed. 

Comment: you can also try jquery which requires less lines of code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think `getElementById` or `querySelector` will make any difference, since the heavier stuff is done when you add a bunch of html elements as a string despite the fact that innerHTML can be vulnerable to cross site scripting if the output of that string has user input commands in it.

But if you still want to do this way you can do by using `` backticks to add as many lines as you'd like.

However, the way I would do is to create those elements on a different function and then output them to your `loadNextStep` function, then adding to your `#content` element using the `appendChild` method.

Here's a quick example of I would do:

```js
function loadNextStep() {   
   var content = document.getElementById('content');
   var step = step1();
   step.forEach( stepContent => {
        content.appendChild( stepContent );
  })
   
}

function step1() {
 
 var someContent = document.createElement('span');
 someContent.innerText =  `This is some content. It seems like I need to write everything in one line to make the command work properly.
 Yes, but if you use backticks you can have multiple lines.`;
 
 var input = document.createElement('input');
 input.type = 'date';
 input.id = 'date-picker';
 
 return [ someContent, input ]
 
}

loadNextStep();
```

```html
<div id="content">

</div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I will try the new way you suggested. Is the getElementById method vulnerable to someone injecting code with the input fields? What do you mean by cross site scripting?

Comment: No, not `getElementById` but `innerHTML` that is